# Do I really need malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, mingw

I understand that malloc is used to dynamically allocate memory. In my code, I have the following function that I sometimes call:

```
int memory_get_log(unsigned char day, unsigned char date, unsigned char month){

    char fileName[11];
    unsigned long readItems, itemsToRead;
    F_FILE *file;

    sprintf(fileName, "%s_%u%u%u%s", "LOG", day, date, month, ".bin");

    file = f_open(fileName , "r");

    itemsToRead = f_filelength( fileName );

    //unsigned char *fileData = (unsigned char *) malloc(itemsToRead);
    unsigned char fileData[itemsToRead]; //here I am not using malloc

    readItems = f_read(fileData, 1, itemsToRead, file);

    transmit_data(fileData, itemsToRead);

    f_close(file);

    return 0;
}
```

As you may see, the number of items I read from the file can be different each time. The line 
`unsigned char fileData[itemsToRead];` is used to read these variable sized files. I can see that I am allocating memory dynamically in some way. This function works fine. Do I really need to use malloc here? 
Is there anything wrong with the way I am declaring this array?

Comment: For a big `itemsToRead` value, your code may create a problem. Static declaration with a variable, is preferred to use for small arrays. As long as your value will be low, your code is fine. However, `malloc`/`calloc` are always safest

Comment: Since you are not using the variable `itemsToRead` outside the function, you may be OK with not using malloc, However as already mentioned you should only do this for smaller sizes of variables.

Comment: The array `fileName` is far too small to fit `LOG_123456.bin` — even if all the numbers are single digits it is too small by one (presumably you forgot the trailing null byte) and they could be triple-digit values.

Comment: On WIndows, by default, the stack size is 1 MiB; on most Unix-like systems, it is 8 MiB.  while you can work around the limits, it is usually simplest not to need to do so.  The `fileData`array needs to be small enough to fit on the stack — so the `itemsToRead` value needs to be small enough too.  Using the name `items` for 'bytes' is a little misleading, but not critically so.

Comment: The main issue is the error handling: how does your program react when you feed it "garbage" input, such as a very large file or an unending stream of character that does not fit your scenario ? You may want to perform some clean-up actions instead of just crashing. This is generally easier to do so with `malloc`.

Comment: Since the VLA is likely gonna end up on the stack, it's not the best idea to use unless the file is guarateed to be small. Couple of hundred bytes on the stack is ok, but if you need more use malloc or static.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR

If you don't know what you're doing, use `malloc` or a fixed size array in all situations. VLA:s are not necessary at all. And do note that VLA:s cannot be static nor global.

> Do I really need to use `malloc` here?

Yes. You're reading a file. They are typically way bigger than what's suitable for a VLA. They should only be used for small arrays. If at all.

## Long version

> Is there anything wrong with the way I am declaring this array?

It depends. VLA:s was removed as a mandatory component from C11, so strictly speaking, you are using compiler extensions, thus reducing the portability. In the future, VLA:s might (The chance is probably extremely low) get removed from your compiler. Maybe you also want to recompile the code on a compiler without support for VLA:s. The risk analysis about this is up to you. But I might mention that the same is true for `alloca`. Although commonly available, it's not required by the standard.

Another problem is if the allocation fails. If you're using malloc, you have a chance to recover from this, but if you're only going to do something like this:

```
unsigned char *fileData = malloc(itemsToRead);
if(!fileData)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

That is, just exit on failure and not trying to recover, then it does not really matter. At least not from a pure recovery point of view.

But also, although the C standard does not impose any requirement that VLA:s end up on the stack or heap, as far as I know it's pretty common to put them on the stack. This means that the risk of failing the allocation due to insufficient available memory is much, much higher. On Linux, the stack is usually 8MB and on Windows 1MB. In almost all cases, the available heap is much higher. The declaration `char arr[n]` is basically the same as `char *arr = alloca(n)` with the exception of how the `sizeof` operator works.

While I can understand that you might want to use the `sizeof` operator on a VLA sometimes, I find it very hard to find a real need for it. Afterall, the size can never change, and the size is known when you do the allocation. So instead of:

```
int arr[n];
...
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(arr), ...
```

Just do:

```
const size_t size = n;
int arr[size];
...
for(int i=0; i<size; ...
```

**VLA:s are not a replacement for `malloc`. They are a replacement for `alloca`. If you don't want to change a `malloc` to an `alloca`, then you should not change to a VLA either.**

Also, in many situations where a VLA would seem to bee a good idea, it is ALSO a good idea to check if the size is below a certain limit, like this:

```
int foo(size_t n)
{
    if(n > LIMIT) { /* Handle error */ }
    int arr[n];
    /* Code */
}
```

That would work, but compare it to this:

```
int foo(size_t n)
{
    int *arr = malloc(n*sizeof(*arr));
    if(!arr) { /* Handle error */ }
    /* Code */
    free(arr);
}
```

You did not really make things that much easier. It's still an error check, so the only thing you really got rid of was the `free` call. I might also add that it's a MUCH higher risk that a VLA allocation fails due to the size being too big. So if you KNOW that the size is small, the check is not necessary, but then again, if you KNOW that it is small, just use a regular array that will fit what you need.

However, I will not deny that there are some advantages of VLA:s. You can read about them [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094467/6699433) But IMO, while they have those advantages they are not worth it. Whenever you find VLA:s useful, I would say that you should at least consider switching to another language.

Also, one advantage of VLA:s (and also `alloca`) is that they are typically faster than `malloc`. So if you have performance issues, you might want to switch to `alloca` instead of `malloc`. A `malloc` call involves asking the operating system (or something similar) for a piece of memory. The operating system then searches for that and returns a pointer if it finds it. An `alloca` call, on the other hand, is typically just implemented by changing the stack pointer in one single cpu instruction.

There are many things to consider, but I would avoid using VLA:s. If you ask me, the biggest risk with them is that since they are so easy to use, people become careless with them. For those few cases where I find them suitable, I would use `alloca` instead, because then I don't hide the dangers.

### Short summary

- VLA:s are not required by C11 and later, so strictly speaking, you're relying on compiler extensions. However, the same is true for `alloca`. So if this is a very big concern, use fixed arrays if you don't want to use `malloc`.
- VLA:s are syntactic sugar (Not 100% correct, especially when dealing with multidimensional arrays) for `alloca` and not `malloc`. So don't use them instead of `malloc`. With the exception of how `sizeof` work on a VLA, they offer absolutely no benefit at all except for a somewhat simpler declaration.
- VLA:s are (usually) stored on the stack while allocations done by malloc are (usually) stored on the heap, so a big allocation has a much higher risk to fail.
- You cannot check if a VLA allocation failed or not, so it can be a good idea to check if the size is too big in advance. But then we have an error check just as we do with checking if `malloc` returned NULL.
- A VLA cannot be global nor static. The static part alone will likely not cause any problems whatsoever, but if you want a global array, then you're forced to use `malloc` or a fixed size array.

> This function works fine.

No it does not. It has undefined behavior. As pointed out by Jonathan Leffler in comments, the array `fileName` is too short. It would need to be at least 12 bytes to include the `\0`-terminator. You can make this a bit safer by changing to:

```
snprintf(fileName, 
         sizeof(fileName), 
         "%s_%u%u%u%s", 
         "LOG", day, date, month, ".bin");
```

In this case, the problem with the too small array would manifest itself by creating a file with extension `.bi` instead of `.bin` which is a better bug than undefined behavior, which is the current case.

You also have no error checks in your code. I would rewrite it like this. And for those who thinks that goto is bad, well, it usually is, but error handling is both practical and universally accepted among experienced C coders. Another common use is breaking out of nested loops, but that's not applicable here.

```
int memory_get_log(unsigned char day, unsigned char date, unsigned char month){

    char fileName[12];
    unsigned long readItems, itemsToRead;
    int ret = 0;

    F_FILE *file;

    snprintf(fileName, 
             sizeof(fileName), 
             "%s_%u%u%u%s", 
             "LOG", day, date, month, ".bin");

    file = f_open(fileName , "r");
    if(!file) { 
        ret = 1; 
        goto END;
    }

    itemsToRead = f_filelength( fileName );

    unsigned char *fileData = malloc(itemsToRead);
    if(!fileData) { 
        ret=2;
        goto CLOSE_FILE;
    }
 
    readItems = f_read(fileData, 1, itemsToRead, file);
    // Maybe not necessary. I don't know. It's up to you.
    if(readItems != itemsToRead) {  
        ret=3;
        goto FREE;
    }

    // Assuming transmit_data have some kind of error check
    if(!transmit_data(fileData, itemsToRead)) {  
        ret=4;
        goto FREE; // Just in case you add another if statement below
                   // and forget to add this
    }

FREE:
    free(fileData);
CLOSE_FILE:
    f_close(file);
END:
    return ret;
}
```

If a function always returns the same value, then it's pointless to return anything. Declare it as void instead. Now I used the return value to make it possible for the caller to detect errors and the type of error.

Comment: Thank you for your informative reply! I do originally have error checks, but I have removed them to make the code shorter for stackoverflow and to help the reader get to the point in the code faster.  It is true that fileName should be 12 bytes but I seem to have missed it.

Comment: Making VLA optional was already C11. But no, a compiler that has this feature will not remove it. Making it optional was only a (failed) strategy to convince more compilers to become conforming.

Comment: @Sarahcartenz I suspected it could be the case that you removed the error checks to create an MRE, but I thought it could be helpful for future readers. I'm glad you liked the answer.

Comment: @JensGustedt True. I changed the answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, the line 'unsigned char fileData[itemsToRead]' asks for memory on stack, and this will be terrible mistake if file size is big. You should use 'malloc' to ask memory on heap.
secondly, if file size is really big enough, you should coside to use virsual memory or dynamic load such as 'fseek' method.