# Dynamic array unknown size C

Tags: c, uwp, pjsip, pjsua2

I have been working with pjsip for a while now, and in an effort to get it to work for UWP, I have encountered a seemingly fatal flaw in the base C code. I am getting errors `'addrs': unknown size` and `'deprecatedAddrs': unknown size` in the code below.

```
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pj_enum_ip_interface2( const pj_enum_ip_option *opt,
                       unsigned *p_cnt,
                       pj_sockaddr ifs[]) {
    pj_enum_ip_option opt_;

    if (opt)
    opt_ = *opt;
    else
    pj_enum_ip_option_default(&opt_);

    if (opt_.af != pj_AF_INET() && opt_.omit_deprecated_ipv6) {
    pj_sockaddr addrs[*p_cnt];
    pj_sockaddr deprecatedAddrs[*p_cnt];
    unsigned deprecatedCount = *p_cnt;
    unsigned cnt = 0;
    int i;
    pj_status_t status;
...
```

The error comes for the two lines `pj_sockaddr addrs[*p_cnt];` and `pj_sockaddr deprecatedAddrs[*p_cnt];` . I feel that I understand that this should not work, due to the fact that C cannot have dynamic arrays and needs to preallocate space. However, pjsip is a well-established library used rather often, so my question is: Is there a situation in which this would function at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid c99 syntax. It's called a [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99). You might want to add the `-std=c99` flag to your compiler.

EDIT:
Given the comments below, here's an example on how to use dynamic memory to replace VLAs.

```c
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pj_enum_ip_interface2( const pj_enum_ip_option *opt,
                       unsigned *p_cnt,
                       pj_sockaddr ifs[]) {
    pj_enum_ip_option opt_;

    if (opt)
    opt_ = *opt;
    else
    pj_enum_ip_option_default(&opt_);

    if (opt_.af != pj_AF_INET() && opt_.omit_deprecated_ipv6) {
    
    /* Dynamically allocate memory to replace VLAs
     * Use calloc if you need it initialized to zero
     */ 
    pj_sockaddr *addrs = malloc((*p_cnt) * sizeof (pj_sockaddr));
    pj_sockaddr *deprecatedAddrs = malloc((*p_cnt) * sizeof (pj_sockaddr));
    
    unsigned deprecatedCount = *p_cnt;
    unsigned cnt = 0;
    int i;
    pj_status_t status;

    ...


    /* Remember that memory allocated from the heap needs to be freed */
    free (addrs);
    free (deprecatedAddrs);
    
    /* Not needed, but a good practice */
    addrs = NULL; 
    deprecatedAddrs = NULL;

    ...
    
    return status;
```

Comment: Ah okay, is there a way to switch to C99 within visual studio? This is part of a larger solution.

Comment: That's another problem.  MSVC doesn't support VLAs.

Comment: @dbush shouldn't MSVC be conforming to standard?

Comment: Is there a way I should be changing the code since "VLA"s are not supported?

Comment: @TonyTannous MSVC does not fully conform to the standards.

Comment: @Scornz yes. Use malloc instead.

Comment: @Scornz You'll need to `malloc` the memory instead.

Comment: @TonyTannous MSVC be conforming to standard? --> See [C99 partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers)

Comment: Exactly how is it good practice to set the pointers to NULL before returning?

Comment: To build the muscle memory, it'll become natural later on, for other (actual useful) scenarios

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gcc or clang, then the flag `std=c99` or something like that.

VLA:s are from C99, but were made optional in C11.

If you're using MSVC, then you're out of luck. It does not support C99. There's a question about that here: [Does Visual Studio 2017 fully support C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615184/6699433)

If you want to change the code to something equivalent, then you could use `alloca`. So change

```
pj_sockaddr addrs[*p_cnt];
```

to

```
pj_sockaddr *addrs = alloca(sizeof *addrs * *p_cnt);
```

That is basically what's going on under the hood of VLA:s anyway, so it's a quick fix. The only difference will be if you're using the `sizeof` operator later on in the code, so if there is a loop somewhere that looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeof addrs; i++) {
    // Code
}
```

Then you would have to do something about that too.

You can use `malloc` instead of `alloca` but that might impact performance and you need to `free` the memory afterwards. Usually, I prefer using `malloc` but since you're not writing this from scratch then it does not really matter. After all, since the original code is using VLA:s, you're not adding any problems.

In short, the problems with VLA:s (and alloca) is that you cannot error check the allocation, and if that you risk blowing up the stack. I wrote an answer about that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163652/6699433

Answer (score 0):

The MSVC compiler does not support every feature from the C99 standard, including variable-length arrays. You can make this code compatible with MSVC by changing the following lines:

```
pj_sockaddr addrs[*p_cnt];
pj_sockaddr deprecatedAddrs[*p_cnt];
```

To use `malloc`:

```
pj_sockaddr *addrs = malloc(*p_cnt * sizeof(pj_sockaddr));
pj_sockaddr *deprecatedAddrs = malloc(*p_cnt * sizeof(pj_sockaddr));
```

Comment: The size is wrong. It should read `(*p_cnt) * sizeof (pj_sockaddr)`

Comment: Still missing the `sizeof` argument