# Segmentation Fault While Sorting - Malloc

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am reading a file of floating point numbers and then sorting them. When I use my following sort and swap functions with 1 million numbers, I am successfully able to sort the numbers. However, when I try to sort 100 million numbers, I get a segmentation fault. I am not sure why because I am dynamically allocating memory. How would I be able to handle more than 1 million numbers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void swap(float *a, float *b, size_t n) {
    size_t numbytes; 
    size_t sz = sizeof(float); 
    void *temp = NULL; 
    
    numbytes = n * sz; 
    if (numbytes == 0){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    temp = malloc(numbytes);
    
    memcpy(temp, a, numbytes);
    memcpy(a,b,numbytes); 
    memcpy(b,temp,numbytes);
    
    free(temp); 
}

void radixSort(float array[], size_t count) {
    int numOfZero = 0; 
    float a[count];
    float *b = a;
    
    for (uint32_t radix=1; radix; radix<<=1) { //unsigned int 32 bit
        uint32_t *arrayToInt = (uint32_t *)array;
        int zeroCount=0;
        int oneCount=0;
        numOfZero=0;
        
        for (int j=0; j < count; ++j)
        numOfZero += !(arrayToInt[j]&radix);
        oneCount=numOfZero;
        
        for (int j=0; j < count; ++j)
        if (arrayToInt[j]&radix){
            b[oneCount]=array[j];
            ++oneCount;
        }
        else{
            b[zeroCount]=array[j];
            ++zeroCount;
        }
        swap(b,array,count);
    }
    if (numOfZero < count){
        memcpy(b+(count-numOfZero), array, numOfZero*sizeof(float));
        
        for (int d=0,j=count-1;j>=numOfZero;j--,d++)
        b[d]=array[j];
        memcpy(array, b, count*sizeof(float));
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd; 
    float num; 
    size_t nr; 
    int eleNum = 0; 
    
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); 
    
    if (fd == -1){
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    struct stat st; 
    fstat(fd, &st); 
    off_t size = st.st_size; 
    for (int j = 0; j < size/4; j++){
        eleNum++; 
    } 
    
    float array[eleNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < eleNum; i++){
        nr = read(fd, &num, sizeof(float));
        if (nr == -1){
            perror("Error reading file"); 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }
        array[i] = num; 
    }
    
    radixSort(array, eleNum);
    
    close(fd); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: A good place to start with be to check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Why the error check in `swap`? If it's zero bytes, just do nothing. You can safely pass a size of zero to `memcpy`.

Comment: Wait. A *hundred million* numbers? Do you understand how a VLA (variable-length array) typically *works* ? This code is a *recipe* for a stack breach.

Comment: Not related, but `for (int j = 0; j < size/4; j++) eleNum++;` is a *very* roundabout way to write `eleNum = size/4;`. Plus, you never check for integer overflow if `size/4` is larger than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I created a file with 1.2 as data. I used `read` to read data into float variable. When I printed it to the console, it prints 0.0000, not the number.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is `size_t sz = sizeof(float); ` needed if your parameter list includes `void swap(float *a, float *b, ...` You already know you have `float` parameters and `sizeof(float)` is only needed in `numbytes = n * sz;`?? Not wrong, just curious? And wouldn't' `eleNum = size / 4;` avoid the loop?

Comment: @RetiredNinja  I was able to print, only with conversion using `strtof()`

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula You created a text file, so you need `strtof` to convert the values back to `float`. The OP, however, is reading a binary file which contains binary `float` values, so they just need to `read` those in as they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These lines:

```
float a[count]; // In radixSort

float array[eleNum]; // In main
```

will never work for such big numbers. VLA:s are (typically and always in practice) allocated on the stack. On Windows systems, the stack is typically 1MB and 8MB on Linux. I have written an answer about VLA:s that would be good for you to read. In short, I would advice not using them. [Do I really need malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163652/6699433)

I'm not sure if changing to `malloc` will solve your problem, but you will not solve it without doing it.

Furthermore, you should check the return value from `malloc` to see if the allocation worked. Then, if your problems persist, I'd recommend compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -fsanitize=address -g`. Use `gdb` or another debugger to find which line causes a segfault and investigate values. Use `valgrind` to detect memory leaks.

And this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size/4; j++){
    eleNum++; 
}
```

is just weird. It's equivalent to `eleNum = size/4`.

This, in `swap`:

```
if (numbytes == 0){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}
```

is completely unnecessary. It's safe to pass 0 for the size argument to `memcpy`. It would just lead to that nothing happens. I could understand this for debugging purposes, but in that case you should print something useful, or even better, use `assert(numbytes > 0)`